# String comparision in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, string-comparison

```
select * from employees
 where last_name between 'A' AND 'E';
```

Why the is answer coming till 'D' not 'E', is there any other way to fetch the details

Comment: Not exactly, Names between A and E, but start with alphabetics

Comment: **String comparison** is done on their **ASCII** values. So, you are comparing the ASCII value of last_name with a single character, which is obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where last_name between 'A' AND 'E';

**String comparison** is not similar as comparing numbers.

String comparison is done on their **ASCII** values. So, you are comparing the ASCII value of **last_name** with a **single character**, which will not give your desired output.

```
SQL> SELECT ename, ASCII(ename), ASCII('A'), ASCII('E') FROM emp;

ENAME      ASCII(ENAME) ASCII('A') ASCII('E')
---------- ------------ ---------- ----------
SMITH                83         65         69
ALLEN                65         65         69
WARD                 87         65         69
JONES                74         65         69
MARTIN               77         65         69
BLAKE                66         65         69
CLARK                67         65         69
SCOTT                83         65         69
KING                 75         65         69
TURNER               84         65         69
ADAMS                65         65         69
JAMES                74         65         69
FORD                 70         65         69
MILLER               77         65         69

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Based on above **ASCII values**, you would get only those rows where you have the ASCII value of the `ename` between `65` and `69`.

You need to use **SUBSTR** to first extract the first character of last_name and compare it with `'A'` and `'E'`.

For example, I am using the standard `emp` table in SCOTT schema and adding two rows with ename starting with `'D'` and `'E'`.

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  SELECT ename FROM emp
  3  UNION
  4  SELECT 'DAWSON' FROM DUAL
  5  UNION
  6  SELECT 'EINSTEIN' FROM DUAL
  7  )
  8  SELECT * FROM DATA
  9  WHERE substr(ename,1,1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'E';

ENAME
----------
ADAMS
ALLEN
BLAKE
CLARK
DAWSON
EINSTEIN

6 rows selected.
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with comparing a multi-character string with a single-character string in and of itself; see my first solution (which is much faster, but equivalent to yours). Also, string comparison is *not* done on ASCII values, but on collation ordering (which coincide when the collation is `ascii_general_ci`).

Comment: @Amadan Where did I say it is wrong to compare a multi-character string to a single-character string? I said OP is doing it incorrectly based on the context. And yes, when you compare two strings, they are compared on their ASCII values.

Comment: Apologies, it seems I was mistaken. Straight up comparison does not utilise collation.

Comment: @Amadan No problem :-)

Answer (score 4):

Your command is perfect for "employees whose names *are* (not start with) from A to E". `"E"` would be in. `"Einstein"` is out, as it is *later* than `"E"`.

```
WHERE last_name >= 'A' AND last_name < 'F'
```

will give you what you want.

Alternately, you can do

```
WHERE SUBSTR(last_name, 1, 1) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'E'
```

but it would be slow, as it would not be able to use the index.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question is why it is not giving till E,

Suppose if I give salary between 2000 to 5000 it will fetch till 5000, then why can't for names, what is the string methodology

Comment: It *is* giving till E. You just don't have any employees that are called `"E"`. The question you wanted to ask is "why it is not giving till employees whose names start with E", and I explained that too.

Comment: To piggy-back on your example, if you do `BETWEEN 2000 AND 5000`, would you expect it to give you `5000.85`? In the same way, `"Einstein"` is not `BETWEEN 'A' AND 'E'`.

Comment: Please read again. Your command is equivalent to `BETWEEN 'A' AND 'F'` now. If you look at my question, I said `< 'F'`, not `<= 'F'`. Your command *would* give you `"F"` *if it was in your table* (since `'F' <= 'F'`), but not `"Franklin"`, because `"Franklin"` is **not** `<= 'F'`. Open a dictionary and look at in which order the words go; `"E"` is before every word that starts with `"E"`, `"F"` is before every word that starts with `"F"`. But *every word that starts with `"E"` is `< 'F'`*.

Comment: Thanks @ Amadan,
I didn't see your second comment, I got it, 
also with substr(last_name,1,1) between 'A' and 'E';

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES
WHERE Last_name Like 'A%'
OR Last_name Like 'E%';
```

This should be the answer....The code you have written will show the names which are A and E exactly....